# como realizar una bandeja de entrada con notificaciones en android e ios

Tags: android, ios, android-sqlite, programación-móvil

buenas tardes, agradecido de ante mano cualquier colaboración.
les cuento tengo un proyecto dividido por estados y  roles de usuario, mi pregunta es:

- Como haría que un usuario master de un estado/municipio publique algo y le llegue la notificación a un usuario estándar solo de ese mismo estado/municipio
  Entonces como capturó cada estado/municipio  de los usuarios para no enviar una notificación al usuario equivocado
  Espero darme a entender

Comment: Hola Gilberto, esta pregunta tiene demasiadas respuesta y no es apropiada para el formato del sitio. Te sugiero que investigues sobre PushNotifications (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) para distribuir la notificación y en cuando a la distinción entre diferentes tipos de usuario, esa lógica la tienes que implementar tu, de tal forma que cumpla tus necesidades.

Comment: Buenas, me parece demasiado amplia la pregunta, tienes algo hecho al respecto? sino empieza por aquí a definir la estrcutura, procedimientos y focaliza donde tienes dudas..

Comment: no, no tengo nada hecho. este seria mi primer proyecto móvil  y la  duda mas grande es sobre las notificaciones, las demás saldran con la marcha

Comment: Gilberto!  No puedo responder a tu pregunta, pero trabaje en algo muy parecido. La logica de tus notificaciones esta en el servidor, me imagino que desde un mantenedor Admin o desde la App ese usuario master puede publicar contenido o algo asi. Dentro de esa funcion, cuando el usuario master publique contenido debes recopilar a todos los usuarios del mismo municipio (me imagino que hay un role id en tu base de datos que diferencia a los usuarios) y con un ciclo recorrer todos los usuarios que cumplan con : mismo municipio , obtienes el token o uuid del dispositivo y envias notificaciones!

Comment: Exacto, esa es la logica. Y mi pregunta se basa en eso como le digo a la app que haga ese ciclo? Igual que en Java o hay ua sintaxis especial para android, como ya dije es mi primera app y estoy viendo tutoriales y leyendo, pero es más lento el proceso